# Moving PictureBox transparent background issue

Tags: c#, image, winforms

probem:

[image: GIF]

moving object:

```
type: pictureBox 
name : RobotAnimation.PicFM;
backcolor: Transparent;
```

background image ->

```
type: picturebox   
name : pictureBox1
```

etc ->

```
RobotAnimation.PicATM.Parent = pictureBox1;
```

step:

```
timerTick += RobotAnimation.PicATM.Location.X +1;
```

problem:

```
moving object -> around moving object -> is flicker
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The word you are looking for is flicker, or tearing.  See [How to eliminate tearing from animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2448831/719186).  Post code that duplicates the problem.